# HMAC-SHA256 Transaction signing

Tags: authentication, hash, one-time-password

Can rfc6238 be used for transaction signing by concatenating the random seed string with transaction details (such as amount and target account number) ? Could a transaction authorization 8-cipher OTP be generated offline using these transaction details?

Comment: I'm not sure what this is about. TOTP is simply HMAC applied over the current Unix ntimestamp and truncated to 8 digits. Sure, you can derive the HMAC key from the transaction details somehow but that isn't "signing". You need to describe in more detail what you have in mind.